# Register user in salesforce?

Tags: apex

Hi this my code register portal users through site into salesforce.

This is my code:

```
public class Registration{
 private static string PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID = '0019000001dNRMn';
 public blob imagebody{get;set;}
public string firstname{get;set;}
public string lastname{get;set;}
public string email{get;set;}
public string username{get;set;}
public string password{get;set;}
public string confirmpassword{get;set;}
 private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

public Registration(){
}

public void rigist(){

if (!isValidPassword()) {
           ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
               Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
           ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
           // return null;
        }   

 User u = new User();
        u.Username = username;
        u.Email = email;
      //  u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;

        String accountId = PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID;
String userId = Site.createportaluser(u, accountId, password);
        if(userId != null) {

            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
              //  return Site.login(username, password, null);
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.SiteRegisterConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
               // return page;
            }
        }
      //  return null;
}

}
```

but by using this i am not registering can any one tell me where the error in my code.....

Comment: In some working code I have the User CommunityNickname, FirstName and LastName are also all set. The `Site.createPortalUser` reports errors that can be seen if you have apex:pageMessages in your page (and you should return a null page reference where userid is null to stay on that page).

Comment: I didn't use any ape:pagemessages i need to return home before i am checking user registering or not ...... user not registering......

Comment: As I've commented, the Site.createPortalUser code reports any errors by adding ApexPages.Message instances. It is possible that the explanation for your failure is in that form and you are not seeing the explanation. The easy way to see those is to stay on the page and use apex:pageMessages. If you want to go to a different page you will have to extract those messages and pass them along to the new page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `communitynickname` because that's also required.

```
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = username;
        u.Email = email;
        u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;

        String accountId = PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID;

        // lastName is a required field on user, but if it isn't specified, 
           the code uses the username
        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);
        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(username, password, null);
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.SiteRegisterConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
               // return null for debugging.
            }
        }
        return null;
```

Also add `pagemessage` tag in your VF page because there are many possible reason(Username not unique). You will get more information from page message and if user registration is successful then it will login you to site other wise it will redirect you to confirm page. You can try `return null` to get more information.